# Does Proguard remove unused code (on Android)

Tags: java, android, proguard

I was just wondering, I am designing a library to use with my Android projects. Now I am starting to include things like the apache FTP jar to support some debug file uploads.

I know that not all projects will use all parts of the library (e.g. some project will not have an FTP upload at all, but wants to use the UI tools from the library).

Now I got three questions:

1. Does Proguard remove unsused sources (own code), like e.g. my UI tool classes, if they are never references from the main project - meaning not used in the application.
2. Does Proguard remove external libraries (e.g. apache ftp jar) if never used. If not, I may include the source, if option 1 applies.
3. How about resource files (not really Proguards job, more IntelliJ or Eclipse) - Example: I write a google map extension using default markers, stored in the library project. If I do not need the maps anyway, do the files get included in each android project - and is there an easy way to prevent that.

Some more backround: I try to keep all my library stuff in one project as long as possible. I don't know a good point to split the library yet, so I don't want to overkill to create seperate libs for everything (did that in the past, and most of the time it was way to much modularization)...

Thanks for any insights,
Chris

Comment: "Desinging" sounds like an interesting process :-)

Comment: Damn german... We got a lot of -ing and normally no -ign - corrected for orthograpic enthusiasts :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does Proguard remove unsused sources

It tries to, when configured properly.

> Does Proguard remove external libraries (e.g. apache ftp jar) if never used.

It tries to, when configured properly.

> How about resource files (not really Proguards job, more IntelliJ or Eclipse) - Example: I write a google map extension using default markers, stored in the library project. If I do not need the maps anyway, do the files get included in each android project - and is there an easy way to prevent that.

No.

Comment: So there is no difference between including source vs. jars in my library. Most jars provide source code too, but if I understand your answer correctly, as long as I figure out how to use Proguard correctly, there is no benefit in e.g. including the apache commons source vs. the jars.

Comment: @Christian: Correct. Proguard doesn't work off the source in any case AFAIK -- it works off of .class files.

Comment: @CommonsWare it would be nice if you have added a basic example how to configure it right.

Comment: @CommonsWare what about classes in android.jar? Does proguard remove those unused classed in android.jar?

Comment: @Raghunandan: Since "classes in android.jar" are never part of your app in the first place, they do not need to be removed. `android.jar` is part of the compile-time classpath, but its contents are not put into your APK.

Comment: @CommonsWare so if i want to store data to database, i will be using sqlite. This means sqlite is not part of my apk. But my app wil be using classes under android/database/sqlite from android.jar.I wll be importing a few classes from the android.jar. Is this right?

Comment: @Raghunandan: "I wll be importing a few classes from the android.jar. Is this right?" -- you will *reference* a few `android.*` classes from the compile-time `android.jar` stubs for those classes. **Those `android.*` classes are not part of your APK file and therefore are not affected by ProGuard**. The real classes are already in your process at runtime, put there by the firmware.

Comment: Not sure if this can be made use of in your case: in our maven project we use the shade plugin to merge multiple jars into one. This way you would not be required to include sources of external libraries, as the class files inside this other JARs effectively become part of your JAR. Be careful with open sure licenses however. Mixing you classes with classes of certain oss license types might cause you problems (legal ones, not technical ones)